# Homomorphism between cyclic groups of orders 7 and 25

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

I am not sure how to start solving this question for my modern algebra course. I understand Lagrange's theorem, but I am not sure if I should use it here. I just need help on where to start.

> Let G and H be cyclic groups of orders 7, m respectively. Let us write eG as the identity of G
>   and eH as the identity of H.
>   Assume that G =< a > and H =< b >. Let f : G → H be a homomorphism such that f(a) = b^r
>   where r > 0 is an integer.
>   Answer the following:
>   If m = 25 show that r must be 0. Explain why this means f(x) = eH for all x ∈ G.

Answer (score 1):

For all $x\in G$, we have that $(f(x))^n=f(x^n)=e_H$ whenever $x^n=e_G$. Therefore, the order of $f(x)$ divides the order of $x$.

Now, what are the possible orders of elements in $G$ and $H$? Can we ever map anything to an element that doesn't have order $1$?

Comment: Possible order of elements in G are 1 and 7, and possible order of elements in H are 1, 5, and 25. We can map an element of order n to an element of order m if gcd(n,m)=1, correct?

Comment: We can map an element of order $n$ to an element of order $m$ if $m$ divides $n$. GCD 1 is kind of the opposite of that.

Comment: Thanks. So, for f(a)=b^r, r must equal 0 because it forces the order of the output to be one. this satisfies the above condition because the order of "a" can either be one or seven. Am I on the right track now? What if the order of "a" is seven?